# SharePoint 2013 workflow from InfoPath 2013 form library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I've created a form in InfoPath 2013 with multiple view.

1st view - Requester (with Submit and Cancel buttons)
2nd view - Action By (with Submit, Approve and Reject buttons)
3rd view - Approved By (with Submit, Approve and Reject buttons)
4th view - Access Denied view

I need to create a workflow using the buttons to submit,approve and reject the form. This form need to publish in Form Library in SharePoint 2013. I saw below link on how to create workflow but it was done in Custom List.

https://jamilhaddadin.com/2011/12/03/implementing-workflow-using-infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-designer-2010/

I've added the 'Action' and 'State' columns but it does not appear in the InfoPath form to add the functions and rules.

Please guide.